# Prolog Code Not Working

Tags: prolog

I have the following code in prolog to produce a path from one node to other but I can't see my results on the screen. I just get **true** as an answer. The last variable name doesn't bind to the results:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,d).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).

path(A,B,P):- 
               path_1(A,B,[A],P).

path_1(A,B,P,Path):- last_element(P,S),S=B.
path_1(A,B,P,Path):-
                  edge(A,X),\+member(X,P),append(P,[X],NewP), 
                  path_1(X,B,NewP,NewP).

last_element([X],X).
last_element([H|T],X):-
                     last_element(T,X).
```

I want to get something like:  `K=[a,b,d]` etc.. when I run this code : `path(a,d,K)` 
but its not showing up. only **true** shows up.

Want to know why. thanks

Comment: Try `trace`. That would help a lot.

Comment: i have traced sooo times but can't find it

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `Path` is not updated in the recursive rule. Change it like this:

```
path_1(A,B,P,Path):-
              edge(A,X),\+member(X,P),append(P,[X],NewP),
              path_1(X,B,NewP,P1), append([A], P1, Path).
```

And it runs well :)

When it is clear that there is an A-X edge and an X-B path, the A-B path should be A + X-B path.

Comment: I think your last line should be append(NewP, [X], Path). Though it is still not working with me. i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The `P` variable in `path/3` will be instantiated when the `Path` variable in `path_1/4` is instantiated.
However, you never use `Path` in `path_1/4` and therefore the variable does not bind to the results as you observed

Since you use swi-prolog you should get a warning like "Singleton variables: [Path]".
While sometimes it is ok to ignore such a warning, most of the times your code is not going to work as you expected

Comment: thanks for your reply. i want to understand something here. the last line in path_1/4 is path_1(X,B,NewP,NewP), so i think "Path" is replaced with the value in NewP and so it must work. Can you explain a little to me why it is not so. thanks. What you are saying is right but i want you to help me why my thinking is wrong

Comment: The first clause of `path_1/4` should bind `Path` to `P`.

Comment: Ok i have done this : path_1(A,B,P,Path):- last_element(P,S),S=B, Path=P. but still get the same "true". Is Path=P wrong?

Comment: @EddyFreeman the Path that is replaced with NewP is the Path in the second call of `path_1/4`, not the Path in the original call